# How to read a string in the form of char array using cin?

Tags: c++, string

how to read a string in the form of char array using cin and using other string functions in cpp.
I tried using a while loop but what is the condition for ending the loop if the size is not given.
Like i used `while('\0')` but it didn't worked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29477567/using-cin-for-char-array

Comment: You may post a [MCVE] of what you tried, and may be we can help you fixing the errors.

Comment: A `while('\0')` loop won't ever even start.

Comment: Programming by randomly guessing will never work. You need to pick up a good book, and actually learn the language.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: _"How can you input '\0' via std::cin.getc() actually?"_ Um, [quite easily](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a23076369478fd68)? (Assuming you fix the typo, seeing as `std::cin.getc()` doesn't exist)

Answer (score 0):

You could use cin.getline():

```
char s[1024];
std::cin.getline(s, 1024, '\n');
std::cout <<  s << std::endl;
```

Comment: The size is not given bro

Comment: I'm aware, which is why I'm using a large array. If you expect the input to be larger than that, make the array larger. Its just one of multiple ways. cin.getline will return once the user inputs 1024 characters or presses enter (the \n character), both of which you can change

Answer (score -1):

If you have a character array, e.g:

```
    char szExample[] = "Hello World";
```

You can process it with:

```
    char* ptr = &szExample[0];
    //Look while ptr doesn't point to null terminator
    while( *ptr ) {
    //Do something...
    //Increment pointer
       ptr++;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

if size is not given then you can set char array size to maximun as u wanted and use 
***scanf()*** for reading the char array and also add header **stdio.h** for use **scanf()** .

example:

```
#include<stdio.h>/#include<cstdio>
char array[100000];
scanf("%s",&array);
```

for knowing the length of inputed char use strlen()

```
int size=strlen(array);
 printf("%s\n",array);
 printf("%d\n",size);
```

input:

ghostrecon

output:

ghostrecon

10

Comment: Don't do these things. That's old fashioned C. The question is about C++.

Comment: I don't need to "try this"; it is bad advice and poor C++. And if you can't get `cin` and `cout` to work properly then you're not using them correctly. There are many questions on SO about this.

Comment: In cpp bro. that is in c

Answer (score -1):

If you are not strict about using a char array it's better to use string datatype.

```
string s;
char delimiter = '\n';
getline(cin, s, delimiter);
```

Here s will read whole line.
If you can keep delimiter as `'\0'` and then s will contain the whole file till EOF.