# How do I get the size of a c-string input in cin?

Tags: c++, arrays, c-strings, cin

So, basically I want to write a program in c++ that encrypts text by moving the chars by a random number in the ascii table. But first I need to get a string by the user. When I want to store the c-string in a char array my problem is that I first need to know the size of the string to have the right size in the array. How can I get it without needing to know the future?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can, just use a `std::string` to store the input.  It will handle becoming the correct size for you.

Comment: If you're set on using C-strings, you cannot know the size of the string in advance - the char array must be allocated before you get input, and thus you must choose some (arbitrary) sufficiently large size for it.

Comment: If you try to use `cin` with a fixed-size `char` array, you could run into buffer overflow problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29477567/using-cin-for-char-array

Comment: `#include <string> #include<iostream> std::string input; std::cin >> input;` (https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-stdstring/)

Comment: Note that you can treat a `std::string` as an array of `char`s, using the `[]` indexing operator: https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/

Comment: @jjramsey Or use range based for loops : `for (const char c : input)` that will prevent you from going out of bounds.

Comment: @PepijnKramer While it's vague, it looks like the writer of the question may be expecting to mutate the characters in the string in a possibly non-sequential order. A range-based `for` loop won't help with that.

Comment: @jjramsey You are correct if that is the case. The const in my example would be a bit too restrictive if he wants to modify each character anyway.

Comment: If you're determined to still use C strings, look up the `getline()` member function (of all C++ istreams).    It works similarly (in net effect) to the `fgets()` function in the C standard library (reading data to an array, with checking to stop reading if a delimiter is encountered AND to avoid writing past a specified buffer length).    Often better to use `std::string` (although there are specialised use cases where dynamic memory allocation must be avoided, which means not using `std::string` (and other dynamically resizable containers), those cases are relatively uncommon in practice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are two simple approaches to solving this problem you have.
You can choose one of them based on the needs of your program.

Here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define METHOD_NUM 1 // set this to 1 for the 1st approach
                     // or 2 for the 2nd approach

int main( )
{
    // an arbitrary size, I chose 20 for demo
    constexpr std::size_t requiredCharsCount { 20 };

#if METHOD_NUM == 1

    std::string user_input { };
    std::size_t buffSize { };

    do
    {
        std::getline( std::cin, user_input );

        // number of chars in the user input
        buffSize = user_input.size( );

    } while ( buffSize > requiredCharsCount );

#else

    // + 1 is for the '\0' aka the null terminator
    constexpr std::size_t buffSize { requiredCharsCount + 1 };
    
    std::string user_input( buffSize, '\0' );
    std::cin.getline( user_input.data( ),
                      static_cast<std::streamsize>( user_input.size( ) ) );

#endif

    std::cout << "The user entered: " << user_input
              << '\n';

    // manipulate the string however you want
    // just make sure that the indices you're using are
    // less than buffSize to avoid buffer overrun
    user_input[0] = '1';
    user_input[5] = 'g';
    user_input[2] = '@';
}
```

To begin with, I recommend you use the `std::string` class because it handles all the necessary allocations/deallocations for you and automatically keeps track of that stuff. A *C-style array* or even a `std::array` won't have this kind of luxury out of the box.

Now, the 1st approach lets the user enter as many characters as they want, and then the program checks the number of characters entered to make sure it's not greater than a predefined number (i.e. `requiredCharsCount` and I have set it to **20**). If it is, then the program will ask for new input. In case you don't want to set a limit for the user you can remove that variable and the `do-while` loop.

Speaking of the 2nd approach, as you can see, it lets the user enter a limited number of characters (again, **20**) and won't read more than the limit even if the user's string contains more than that. This approach is more efficient but obviously has the limitation that I just mentioned.

Comment: Links to the docs: [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) --- [std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) --- [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)